# Autoincrement in oracle11g and JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver, prepared-statement

I'm developping an application that connects to an Oracle 11g database, using ojdbc6 as the JDBC driver. I created a trigger and a sequence for the table where I need to add value, so that the ID column of that table autoincrements. All works fine when I add a new row manually in the database with SQL Developper (My sequence and trigger for autoincrement work well). But when it comes to add new lines from my Java application, I get the following error :

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: internal error
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePre
>   paredStatement.java:3071)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(Or
>   aclePreparedStatement.java:2247)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePrep
>   aredStatement.java:3444)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePrepar
>   edStatement.java:3530)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(Oracl
>   ePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)

This is my Java code :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getEmail());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I didn't add the code for my sequence and trigger because I don't think the problem come form the database, since all works fine with sqldevelopper.
I also tried to use my sequence directly, like  :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) VALUES (SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

But that also failed

Could someone help me to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query Provide some default value to this

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 0); // Providing default value as 0
    preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getUsername());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPassword());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getFirstName());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getFirstName());
    preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getEmail());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't send the `ID` from the client, let the trigger handle the `ID`:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL)"
  + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getFirstName());
preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getFirstName());
preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getEmail());

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) VALUES (0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Your auto increment trigger will update the 0 to the next value in the sequence.